# jQuery Mobile call function during page change

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile and want to call a function after clicking on an anchor. This function will put data in the listview visible on the called page. Unfortunately it does not work. Here is some code, I really hope you can help me!

```
<a href="#pageXY" onclick="changeActorInfo(5)" data-transition="flip">
   <img class="tmdbCast1" width="100" height="150">
   <span id="springboardLabelActors" class="tmdbCast1name"></span>
</a>
```

Firebug returns the followin:
Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Thank you for your help! If you need more just tell me!

Edit:

```
function changeActorInfo(cID) {

actorID = cID;
getActorInfo(actorID);
```

};

```
function getActorInfo(pID){
$('.dListDarsteller').show().listview('refresh');
$('.logoListDarsteller').hide();
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/" +pID+ "?api_key=XXX&append_to_response=credits",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
        var name = results.name;
        $('.tmdbTitelDarsteller').html('<br><span class="titel">' +name);
        (...)
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Pls post the code inside changeActorInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is calling `.listview('refresh');` before the content has been initialized by jQuery Mobile. In any case you only be calling `.listview('refresh');` after dynamic content has been added to your listview object.